# Applying background color to component in ember js

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a toolbar component which has a list of items. When I click on an element I need to add background color to the clicked element. Also need to deselect the previously selected item.

I tried using classNameBinding but it applies to all the elements in the list.

How can I apply Background Color to the elements which are clicked inside the Component

In Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/test-toolbar">
  <ul>
     <li {{bindAttr class="bgColor"}} {{action 'redClick'}}> 
      Red
     </li>
     <li {{bindAttr class="bgColor"}}>
      Yellow
     </li>
     <li {{bindAttr class="bgColor"}}>
      Blue
     </li>
  </ul>
</script>


<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <div>
    {{test-toolbar}}
  </div>
</script>
```

In app.js:

```
App.TestToolbarComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  classNameBindings: ['bgColor'],
  bgColor: false,

  actions: {
    redClick: function () {
       this.set('bgColor', true);
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the working DEMO:  [JSBIN LINK](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gazisu/2/edit#J%3aL14)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using actions you can't get the target element to manipulate it. Also using 3 different actions for same is something i don't suggest. You can use `click` hook to handle this in simple jquery way. here is code and jsbin link

```
App.TestToolbarComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  click: function(event){
    var elem = Ember.$(event.target);
    if(elem.is('li')) {
      this.$('li').removeClass('active');
      elem.addClass('active');
    }
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qiriwi/2/edit

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can we achieve the same using classNameBinding, instead of using jQuery to manipulate the classname.

Comment: its possible if you have 3 different classnames bindings for 3 different li's which may complicate since other two needs to be set false when one is true...

Answer (score 0):

The answers given will definitely work. But I think there is a very simple way to get this done. You will have a `.css` (most probably style.css) file associated with your ember app. In that file add the following snippet:

`.active{
       /*your code goes here
       eg. background-color: 'red';*/
}`

This will simply allow you to style the component whichever is active at that moment of time.